# javascript regex - match between slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a URL: https://api.example.com/main/user1/collection1/contents/folder1/test.js

To capture only `collection1`, I tried the following but it returns `user1` along with it, how can I exclude `user1`?

`(?:\/user1\/)[^\/]*`

To capture only `folder1/test.js`, the following also returns `contents` and I want to exclude it

`contents\/(.*)$`

Comment: replace : with <= `(?<=\/user1\/)[^\/]*`, same thing with contents `(?<=contents\/)(.*)$`

Comment: @LanceToth FYI that only works in Chrome

Comment: @Paulpro ah, in that case, put them in () and capture the second group

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regex. you could try `(?:\/user1\/)([^\/]+)` to capture only `collection1`.

This captures the part after `/user1/` in a capturing group `([^\/]+)`.

```js
const pattern = /\/user1\/([^\/]+)/;
const str = "https://api.example.com/main/user1/collection1/contents/folder1/test.js";
matches = str.match(pattern);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

To capture only `folder1/test.js` you could use [`folder1\/.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/WRLmvh/2)

```js
const pattern = /folder1\/.*$/;
const str = "https://api.example.com/main/user1/collection1/contents/folder1/test.js";
matches = str.match(pattern);
console.log(matches[0]);
```

Without regex you might use [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL):

```js
const str = "https://api.example.com/main/user1/collection1/contents/folder1/test.js";
const url = new URL(str);
const parts = url.pathname.split('/');
console.log(parts[3]);
console.log(parts[5] + '/' + parts[6]);
```